# Set group permissions as owner permissions

Tags: files, permissions, recursive

I need to set the same permissions of owner to group recursively to all elements in a directory.

Comment: Only for `rwx`? Or also for `s`? (note that `s` has a different meaning for user/group and regular/directory files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fairly simple answer
(although I don't know for sure whether it works on all versions of *nix);
simply do

```
chmod g=u *
```

i.e., set the **g**roup permissions equal to the **u**ser permissions.

This is documented in [chmod(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod):

> The format of a symbolic mode is [**`ugoa`**...][[**`+-=`**][*perms*...]...],
>   where *perms* is either zero or more letters from the set **`rwxXst`**,
>   or a single letter from the set **`ugo`**.  …
>
> ︙
>
> The letters **`rwxXst`** select …. 
>   Instead of one or more of these letters, you can specify exactly one of the letters **`ugo`**:
>   the permissions granted to the user who owns the file (**`u`**),
>   the permissions granted to other users
>   who are members of the file’s group (**`g`**), and the permissions granted
>   to users that are in neither of the two preceding categories (**`o`**).

Comment: on RHEL 6 it's documented in:
info coreutils 'Symbolic modes'

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for my problem. I want to open r/x permissions of a directory with subfolders but do not want to change everything to +x.  I tried to set umask 022 then 'cp -r' but unfortunately the umask is applied complimentary to the original permissions. With this post's solution, i can do 'chmod -R og=u' then 'chmod -R og-w'

Comment: @fchen: (1) If you want to be cautious, and go step by step, and see what happens, that’s fine.  But you can combine your two commands into one: `chmod -R og=u,og-w` or even `chmod -R og=u-w`.  (2) I guess all your files (and directories) are readable to you, and you’re using `og=u` as a tricky way of copying the `r` bit down to the “group” and ”other” bitfields.  In that case, you can simply do `chmod -R og=rX` (with a capital `X`).  The capital `X` means set the `x` bit if at least one other `x` bit is already set.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  On the other hand, if you have files that aren’t readable to you, and you want to change 100 (`---x------`) into 111 (`---x--x--x`) and 300 (`--wx------`) into 311 (`--wx--x--x`), then your approach is probably as good as you can get.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

On a (recent for `sed`'s `-z`) GNU system, you could do something like:

```
find . ! -type l -printf '%m:%p\0' |
  sed -Ez '/^.?(.)\1.:/d;s/(.)(.)(.):/\1\1\2\x0/' |
  xargs -r0n2 echo chmod
```

(remove `echo` when satisfied with the result).

Note that it only addresses the `r`, `w`, `x` bits not the special ones.

If you don't want it recursive:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type l -printf '%m:%p\0' |
  sed -Ez '/^.?(.)\1.:/d;s/(.)(.)(.):/\1\1\2\x0/' |
  xargs -r0n2 echo chmod
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for file in $(find .); do
   perm=$(stat -c "%a" ${file});
   echo chmod ${perm:0:1}${perm:0:1}${perm:2:1} ${file};
done
```

Remember to remove `echo`.

Improved version:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'for file do
   perm=$(stat -Lc "%a" "$file")
   echo chmod "${perm:0:1}${perm:0:1}${perm:2:1}" "$file"
done' sh {} +
```

As in [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/190695/23408#190699),

- Use `-mindepth 1` to avoid processing `.`.
- Use `-maxdepth 1` to avoid recursion (entering subdirectories).
- Use  `! -type l`  to avoid processing symbolic links
  (although this answer will handle symbolic links OK).

Note that this command will not work correctly for files
that have any of the high-order mode bits (setuid, setgid, and sticky) set.